# C : explain theory behind

Tags: c, r, theory

I have minimal experience with C, but have been asked to convert a C program into R. There is one bit troubling me:

I have a function that takes an int

```
int a
```

and within the function i have an array:

```
double b[3] = {

       1.8293,
       -0.592,
       2.3330,
}
```

and later on in the function i have:

```
c = b[a];
```

can someone tell me what this line is doing? what is being assigned to c? is it simply an array of size b, where all the values of b have been multiplied by a?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn C.

Comment: From the answers it appears that the line does the same in C as in R. You only need to be aware that the index starts at 1 in R and not at 0.

Comment: Btw why do you want to convert from C to R? Usually this is done the other way arround to improve performance. You can call C functions from R.

Comment: yes, i do feel a bit silly now. and with regards to converting from C to R - my boss wants it done in R as he can only use R.

Comment: Learn about the `.C` function in R, that way you can just write a wrapper in R for your C code, then your boss can run it from R and you don't need to translate everything (and it will probably be faster).

Answer (score 3):

`c` is assigned with the `a` *th* value of array `b[]`.

if `a` is equal to 1 then `c` will be equal to `-0.592`

Answer (score 2):

if a contains 0 then `c = b[a]` means that the first element of the array b[] is assigned to a, without changing array b

Answer (score 2):

The variable a here is an index into the array. For example if a=0, then b[a] is the first element (1.8293 in this case).

In general b[a] extracts out a particular element from the array.

Answer (score 2):

So here's a mock up of your function as you described it (I made up the parts you failed to mention) I added comments `//` to explain what is going on:

```
void foo(int a)
{
    // define an array of 3 doubles
    //b[0] = 1.8293
    //b[1] = -0.592
    //b[2] = 2.333

    double b[3] = { 1.8293, -0.592, 2.3330 };

    double c;     // Note c is a double, because we're going to assign 
                  // one of the values from b

    //we're going to use a to access array b, that means a has to be 0, 1, or 2
    if(a < 3)
       c = b[a]; 

    //Now c is set to one of those three values in b 
    //(depending on what value a has)

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The a'th element of the `double` array `b` is assigned to `c` (the first element has index 0).

Answer (score 1):

you need to make some step in C learning.

b[a] means that you will get the content of element with index a from b array